# append values under element in json

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed, jq

the following parameter include list values ( list of  machines )
for example

```
echo $list_of_machine

worker01.sys645.com worker02.sys645.com worker03.sys645.com worker04.sys645.com worker05.sys645.com
```

we have this standard json

```
{
  "MNN_server": [
    "master02.sys645.com"
  ],
  "HTTP_SERVER": [
    "master01.sys645.com",
  ]
}
```

how to append the values - $list_of_machine under **HTTP_SERVER** element , as the following

expected results

```
{
  "MNN_server": [
    "master02.sys645.com"
  ],
  "HTTP_SERVER": [
    "master01.sys645.com",
    "worker01.sys645.com",
    "worker02.sys645.com",
    "worker03.sys645.com",
    "worker04.sys645.com",
    "worker05.sys645.com"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Without knowing the data super well any attempts with awk and/or sed and scripting are likely to fail ... try these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42245288/add-a-new-element-to-an-existing-json-array-using-jq  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51147753/append-json-objects-using-jq https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48963263/append-data-to-json-file-with-jq

Comment: the target is to append the list of machine under - HTTP_SERVER

Comment: And it's guaranteed to have a line `    "master01.sys645.com",` ? Btw, that trailing comma is not valid JSON ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your "standard JSON" isn't actually JSON (there's an extra comma before the closing `]` in `HTTP_SERVER`).

Also, `sed` will only work if the source is formatted in the way you need it, it won't work for arbitrary JSON (which may not have line breaks).

So a better solution is to use `jq`, as in

```
$ jq --arg list "$list_of_machine" '.HTTP_SERVER|=.+($list|split(" "))' < your_file.json 
{
  "MNN_server": [
    "master02.sys645.com"
  ],
  "HTTP_SERVER": [
    "master01.sys645.com",
    "worker01.sys645.com",
    "worker02.sys645.com",
    "worker03.sys645.com",
    "worker04.sys645.com",
    "worker05.sys645.com"
  ]
}
```

with a well-formed `your_file.json`, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the `bash` shell, you have access to arrays.  Use an array to store your list of machines:

```bash
machines=(
        worker01.sys645.com
        worker02.sys645.com
        worker03.sys645.com
        worker04.sys645.com
        worker05.sys645.com
)
```

In the case that you happen to find yourself with a shell that does not use arrays, use the list of positional parameters:

```bash
set --  worker01.sys645.com \
        worker02.sys645.com \
        worker03.sys645.com \
        worker04.sys645.com \
        worker05.sys645.com
```

The `jq` tool is able to take a list at the end of its list of arguments, if you prepend it with `--args`, and will then allow you to access that list using `$ARGS.positional` (a JSON array) within the `jq` expression.

You can then append the list of machines to your JSON file, assuming its syntax is correct (your example contains a comma in the wrong place):

```bash
jq '.HTTP_SERVER += $ARGS.positional' file.json --args "${machines[@]}"
```

Or, with the list in the list of positional parameters:

```bash
jq '.HTTP_SERVER += $ARGS.positional' file.json --args "$@"
```

Note that `--args` and the list of strings must be the last thing on the command line.

The output will go to the standard output stream.

Answer (score 0):

With slightly different indentation.

```
$ sed 's/\("master01.sys645.com",\)/\1'$(echo -e "\\\\n\\\\t\"${list_of_machine// /\",\\\\n\\\\t\"}\"")'/' json
{
  "MNN_server": [
    "master02.sys645.com"
  ],
  "HTTP_SERVER": [
    "master01.sys645.com",
        "worker01.sys645.com",
        "worker02.sys645.com",
        "worker03.sys645.com",
        "worker04.sys645.com",
        "worker05.sys645.com"
  ]
}
```